# ArgumentError in Shakes#index , nil is not a valid asset source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi guys when iam trying to pull image using image tag its giving nil is not a valid asset source ive image file in my assests , strangely this problem is only occuring when iam trying use decorator pattern else without it image is being properly displaye ,Iam fairly new to this can any of the experts shred some light what am i doing wrong ?
Thanks

```html
require 'shake_decorator'

class ShakesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shake, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /shakes
  # GET /shakes.json
  def index
    @shakes = Shake.all
  end

  # GET /shakes/1
  # GET /shakes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /shakes/new
  def new
    @shake = Shake.new
  end

  # GET /shakes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /shakes
  # POST /shakes.json
  def create
  
     @shake = Shake.new()
     @shake.Name=params[:shake][:Name]
     @shake.Cost=params[:shake][:Cost]
     @shake.Calories=params[:shake][:Calories]
   
  
   # create an instance/object of a BasicCar
   


     myShake=BasicShake.new(@shake.Cost,@shake.Calories)


    #add the extra features to the new car
   if params[:shake][:caramel].to_s.length > 0 then
     myShake = CaramelDecorator.new(myShake)
   end
   if params[:shake][:pbutter].to_s.length > 0 then
     myShake = PeanutbutterDecorator.new(myShake)
   end
   if params[:shake][:cream].to_s.length > 0 then
     myShake = CreamDecorator.new(myShake)
   end
      #populate the cost and the description details
    @shake.Cost = myShake.cost
    @shake.description = myShake.details

     #retrieve the instance/object of the MyLogger class
  
 

       respond_to do |format|
      if @shake.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shake, notice: 'Shake was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shake }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shake.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shakes/1
  # DELETE /shakes/1.json
  def destroy
    @shake.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shakes_url, notice: 'Shake was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shake
      @shake = Shake.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def shake_params
      params.require(:shake).permit(:Name, :Cost, :Calories, :image_url)
    end
end
```

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Shakes</h1>

<table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      <th>Image url</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @shakes.each do |shake| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= shake.Name %></td>
        <td><%= shake.Cost %></td>
        <td><%= shake.Calories %></td>
           <td><%= image_tag(shake.image_url, :class => 'list_image' ,:style => "height:100px") %></td>

    


    
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', shake %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_shake_path(shake) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', shake, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Shake', new_shake_path %>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your expected behaviour and what's the actual? Also, please don't post code that is not relevant to your question (like other controller actions) and please try harder with punctuation in your English.

Comment: Expected behavior is image should be displayed ..but iam getting ArgumentError in Shakes#index , nil is not a valid asset source Erro